# Integrating out the fluctuations of a field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral

I was reading the theory of superfluidity in the language of field integrals from the book 'Condensed matter field theory' by A Altland and B Simons. The quantum partition function is given by $$Z=\int D(\rho,\phi)\exp(-S[\rho,\phi])$$ where $$S=\int d\tau \int dr[i\delta \rho \partial_\tau \phi + \frac{\rho_0}{2m}(\nabla \phi)^2+ \frac{g \rho^2}{2}].\tag{6.11}$$
It is mentioned that a gausssian integration over the density fluctuation $\delta \rho$ gives the effective action $$S=\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau \int dr[\frac{1}{g}(\partial_\tau \phi)^2 + \frac{\rho_0}{m}(\nabla \phi)^2 ]\tag{6.12}.$$
How does one perform the following integration? $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\rho \exp(-\int d\tau \int dr [ i\delta \rho \partial_\tau \phi + \frac{\rho_0}{2m}(\nabla \phi)^2+ \frac{g \rho^2}{2}]). $$
Do we just complete the square as usual and ignore the integrals wrt time $\tau$ and $r$? Or rather perform this integration?,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\rho \exp(- [i\delta \rho \partial_\tau \phi + \frac{\rho_0}{2m}(\nabla \phi)^2+ \frac{g \rho^2}{2}])$$
I have attached a page for reference.

[image: For reference]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A&S are trying to say that one should perform a Gaussian [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). Here the path integration variable
$$\rho({\bf r},\tau)~=~\rho_0+\underbrace{\delta\rho({\bf r},\tau)}_{\text{fluctuations}}\tag{p.261}$$ is a field, i.e. a function of spacetime, so there are infinitely many [Gaussian integrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral): Formally speaking 1 integration for each spacetime point. (This should be regularized, e.g. via a discretization of spacetime.) A&S ignore$^1$ the functional determinant, and only sum up the action contributions (=the classical contributions) in eq. (6.12).

--

$^1$ A&S also seem to have added a total derivative term $i\rho_0\partial_{\tau}\phi$ to the action (6.11).

Comment: By discretization of spacetime, you mean the method known as 'time slicing' right?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Partially.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add something to Qmechanic's answer. In some cases, you can also arrive at the desired solution by simply finding the equations of motion for the relevant degree of freedom (in this case $\rho$) and plugging in the path integral.

We can carry out this computation straightforwardly. The equation of motion for $\rho$ is

\begin{equation}
\rho= -\frac{i}{g}\partial_\tau \phi
\end{equation}

Plugging this solution to your action should give you the desired formula. Now, you may wonder what is the reason for this procedure and why they give the same answer.

When we are integrating out some degree of freedom in the path integral, we assume that the field (or particle) we are integrating out does not do something interesting in energies we probe the system. Therefore, we average it over and include its effect through different interaction terms or by modifying the coupling constants of other fields. To put it another way, we assume that the field, in the scale of interest doesn't fluctuate wildly and the path integral only receives contribution from paths that follow the classical equation of motion. This is why they give the same answer. The field doesn't get wildly excited so it wanders only around the classical equation of motion and justifies plugging in the classical equation of motion in the path integral!

Comment: Though I have to add that this is a pretty dirty and quick way to get an effective field theory and the proper way to do is to expand the functional determimant as Qmechanic mentioned.